# Access denied to SSH server running in raspberry pi

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, ssh-keys, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to do ssh connection from Ubuntu machine to a pi. I am getting the following messages
Command:

```
ssh -vv PI_ipaddress -l pi
```

Screen output:

```
OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu1.2, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.218.96.209 [10.218.96.209] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/hadoop-user/.ssh/identity type -1
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug1: identity file /home/hadoop-user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug1: identity file /home/hadoop-user/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu1.2
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 141/256
debug2: bits set: 509/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '10.218.96.209' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/hadoop-user/.ssh/known_hosts:16
debug2: bits set: 525/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/hadoop-user/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/hadoop-user/.ssh/id_rsa (0xb7f1e598)
debug2: key: /home/hadoop-user/.ssh/id_dsa (0xb7f1e5b0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/hadoop-user/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/hadoop-user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: /home/hadoop-user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
pi@10.218.96.209's password:
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@10.218.96.209's password:
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@10.218.96.209's password:
```

Note:

1. If I use ssh in my pi, it works. But from other systems, I am unable to access.
2. The password I entered is correct. No issues there.
3. I reinstalled ssh in pi, still it does not work.
4. I tried disabling GSSAPI from a windows machine(just cross-checking).Still no connection
5. I googled the issue and I could not arrive at a solution
6. Ping works from

any system to the pi.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have two guesses what it might be. 1 is that port forwarding is not set up for the ssh-server. Redirect port 22 on your router to port 22 on the raspberry pi. 2 is that the username that was given is not correct. It appears to be using pi as the username to login. What is the command that you used to connect to the ssh server from inside the pi?

Comment: 1. Could you give me some resources on port-forwarding. I am entirely new at this. 2. "ssh -vv PI_ipaddress -l pi" I used the same command from all the systems. No change in that

Comment: I'm not sure if the ip address you are using is an internal or external ip address. If you look at your network from the outside, there is only 1 ip address even though there are multiple devices. This is why port forwarding is necessary, so the router knows what device to send an incoming message to. But, if you use the internal ip address, you should be able to connect to the pi without port forwarding. Start here: http://portforward.com/english/applications/port_forwarding/SSH/default.htm Select your router from the list, and it will show you step by step how to do the port forwarding.

Comment: check the server log. There should be reason for rejecting your password. But my guess is that you played with `AllowUsers` and similar options in `sshd_config`.

Comment: @TonyRuth : I just read through the link. I am not using any router configuration. Pi is just peer-peer connected to ubuntu system via LAN. Hence I don't think there would be any issues with that.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution is sort of intuitive. The keyboard layout between the Pi and ubuntu system were not the same and hence gave out error while giving password which was unknown to the user.